# HealthKit background delivery

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

Has anyone else had issues with `enableBackgroundDeliveryForType` with HealthKit? It works perfectly on my iPhone 4s - I can see NSLog statements running in the background, and I get the UILocalNotification that I set up in the associated observer query - but it is only working sporadically on my iPhone 5s.

On the 5s, I've gotten only a handful of notifications when I try entering data through the Health app (even though performing the same steps on the 4s works just fine). Most of the time, I don't get any notifications when my app is in the background, but when I bring it to the foreground I get all the notifications right away.

I know the code isn't the issue, since it's working fine on one device and it *has* worked on the 5s as well, just rarely. I've also tried rebooting my phone and uninstalling/reinstalling the app.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35073904/1677480

Answer (score 1):

In the [iOS 8.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html) you'll find this under the HealthKit section:

```
Fixed in iOS 8.1 Beta
Background delivery of HealthKit data does not work as expected.
```

So I think the solution to your problem is to upgrade/wait for iOS 8.1 to be released. You should be able to get the new betas from the developer center to test.